# Access property of a property Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

It should be some of the basics, but I could not find a way to solve it through 2 days googling..
Anyway, here it is.
I am having an

```
array_1 = [1,2,3...]
```

where every element is unique, i.e. are IDs
Also, I am having an

```
Obj_1 = {2001=[2073,183,11],2011=[101,7,83,179], 2089=[1,11], ...}
```

Objective: match array elements for every property of `Obj_1` with the elements of `array_1` and if matched, add the property - ID of the matched element (from `array_1`) - to the `Obj_2` and add the whole array from the matched value (of `Obj_1`) to this property.
Example. When I am going through the property `2001` of `Obj_1`, the ID `11` will match the array. Then I want the property `11` added to the `Obj_2` with the value, so that in the end

```
Obj_2 = {11:{2001:[2073,183,11],2089:[1,11]}, 7:{}, 1:{}..}
```

I wrote this code that saves it as arrays in the following form without adding the property key from Obj_1.

```
var Obj_2 = {};
var key1 = 0;
for (var i in array_1) {
Obj_2[array_1[i]] = []; 
for (var x in Obj_1){ 
  for (var m in Obj_1[x]){ 
    if (Obj_1[x][m]==array_1[i]){ 
      key1 = array_1[i];
      Obj_2[key1].push(Obj_1[x]); 

                                 }
                           } 
                      } 
                         }
```

Hence, the result I am getting now is
`Obj_2 = {11:[[2073,183,11],[1,11]], 7:[[]], 1:[[]] ...}`

The major problem is that I don't know

`1. how to access the property of a property (especially with respect to the differences between when a property exists and when it doesn't)`

`2. how to add the value for the property of a property`

Pointing into the right direction would be much appreciated. Just the end note, it's a script on Google Script, but I suppose it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3c9Lwo3t/) here.

```
var indexes = [1, 3, 5];
var Obj_1 = {'100':[3,183,1],'200':[101,5,2,179],'300':[1,11]};
var Obj_2 = { };
var needle = 0;

for (var i in indexes) {
    needle = indexes[i];
    Obj_2['' + needle] = { };
    for (var prop_1 in Obj_1) {
        var haystack = Obj_1[prop_1];
        if (haystack.indexOf(needle) >= 0) {
            Obj_2[needle]['' + prop_1] = haystack;
        }
    }
}

console.log(Obj_2);
```

Care when manipulate Objects and Arrays in Javascript, they don't have the same structure, but the item access operator ( [] ) is the same.

Comment: yeah, this is strange.. I haven't found this anywhere else. So actually for a property of a property of a property, I'd use obj[][][]?

Comment: Yes ! In some cases, if you use the [] operator with an integer index, it creates an Array with the prototype of Object. And vice-versa. That's why i cast your indexes in string values.